# Сбросить все стили для элемента

Tags: css, bootstrap

На уже существующюю страницу сайта (для справки Sharepoint 2007) надо встроить кусок на bootstrap 3. Все более-менее ok, но часть стилей все-таки наследуется от шаропойнта - размер шрифтов и некоторые другие. Можно ли как то настроить bootstrap, чтобы сбросить стили только для определенного элемента?

Comment: 1 .В ручную, проверив какие стили вас беспокоят. 2. Убрав класс который навешивает стиль на элемент. Других вариантов нет. 3. Правильно писать CSS не делая крутых зависимостей, да и вообще каких либо.

Comment: я, к сожалению, пока не очень в верстке - тулзы хрома показывают что font-size например для table (в sharepoint 2007 все на таблицах) наследуется от user agent stylesheet. И вся разметка bootstrap находится в куске этой таблицы.